# tried installing brew it shows installed but when i type brew its showing -bash: brew: command not found

Tags: homebrew

when i tried installing brew through this command

```
ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"
```

it showed me

> It appears Homebrew is already installed. If your intent is to reinstall you
>   should do the following before running this installer again:
>   `rm -rf /usr/local/Cellar /usr/local/.git && brew cleanup`

but when I type

`brew` in terminal it shows

> -bash: brew: command not found

Answer (score 1):

Maybe brew is just not available in your path. Have you tried "uninstalling" it as  told:

```
rm -rf /usr/local/Cellar /usr/local/.git && brew cleanup
```

And then reinstall it? Also probably closing the terminal and then reopening it could be an easy solution to make your terminal recognize a changed path

Comment: Geofes-MacBook-Pro:~ Geofe$ rm -rf /usr/local/Cellar /usr/local/.git && brew cleanup
-bash: brew: command not found

Comment: Did you install as root (which you should not be doing)? It is probably uninstalled. Try reinstalling. As https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/blob/master/share/doc/homebrew/Installation.md#installation suggests if it was installed it should be located at "/usr/local".  Also useful to check if your requirements are met: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/blob/master/share/doc/homebrew/Installation.md#requirements